# upload file with Alamofire swift 4

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm trying to upload image using Alamofire (swift 4.2), but when converting image to data I got this error
Extra argument 'compressionQuality' in call

the code is

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire

class APIUpload {
    class func createPhoto(photo: UIImage, completion: @escaping (_ error:Error?, _ success: Bool)->Void){
        let url = "http://www.fb.test/photo.php"
        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (form: MultipartFormData) in
            let data = photo.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0){
                form.append(data:Data, withName:"photo",fileName:"photo.jpeg",mimeType:"image/jpeg")
            }
        }, usingThreshold: SessionManager.multipartFormDataEncodingMemoryThreshold, to: url, method: .post, headers: nil) { (result: SessionManager.MultipartFormDataEncodingResult) in
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                completion(error, false)
            case .success(request: let upload, streamingFromDisk: _, streamFileURL: _):
                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress: Progress) in
                    print(progress)
                })
                upload.responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response: DataResponse<Any>) in
                    switch response.result{
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error)
                    case .success(let value):
                        let json = JSON(value)
                        print(json)
                        completion(nil, true)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/se7fH.png)

Comment: I suspect the error message is a little misleading here. Why is `form.append` inside a closure at the end of `jpegData`?

Answer (score -1):

Signature of `jpegData`

```
func jpegData(compressionQuality: CGFloat) -> Data?
```

so you need

```
if let data = photo.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0){
      form.append(data:data, withName:"photo",fileName:"photo.jpeg",mimeType:"image/jpeg")
}
```